# Specify linters in lintr::lint

Tags: r, lintr

I cannot figure out how to turn off specific linters using lintr. The documentation offers an example (for vim/syntastic, which is what I'm using), which is not very clear:

```
let g:syntastic_r_lintr_linters = "with_defaults(line_length_linter(120))"
```

Apparently all this does is change a default. Do I need to list all the linters I want to use here? Is there a way to exclude just a couple?

I assume there's something like

```
let g:syntastic_r_lintr_linters_nonportable_path_linter = 0
```

but I can't find the right syntax.

Apparently `g:syntastic_r_lintr_linters` is supposed to be a list of linters. But it's not clear what syntax is supposed to work.

If we forget about the vim syntax and head right to the R package `lintr` (which vim/syntastic calls) and the `linters` argument of `lint` then this works:

`lint(file.R, linters=assignment_linter)`

This doesn't (no error, but doesn't catch mistakes in code):

`lint(file.R, linters=list(assignment_linter, single_quotes_linter))`

Nor does this (errors out):

`lint(file.R, linters=list('assignment_linter', 'single_quotes_linter'))`

But this does:

`lint('file.R',linters=list('assignment_linter'=assignment_linter,'single_quotes_linter'=single_quotes_linter))`

So maybe it's supposed to be a named list?

Comment: `g:syntastic_r_lintr_linters` is supposed to be an R list of linters, `with_defaults()` is just a convenient way to build this list.  This is more or less [documented](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr/tree/master/man).

Comment: Yeah I've read that, but a list of linters doesn't work. See edits above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to turn off specific linters is to add this (for example) to vimrc:

```
let g:syntastic_r_lintr_linters = "with_defaults(single_quotes_linter=NULL)"
```

This is not in the documentation. I had to dig through some old (closed) issues on github to find this.

Furthermore, `lintr::lint` does indeed expect a named list for the `linters` argument, but will now accept an unnamed list (see https://github.com/jimhester/lintr/issues/224). So this should work to make a list from scratch:

```
let g:syntastic_r_lintr_linters = "list(assignment_linter, single_quotes_linter")
```

Comment: alternatively, you can take a named subset of the default linter list as follows:  `let g:syntastic_r_lintr_linters = "default_linters[c('assignment_linter', 'single_quotes_linter')]"`