# Customize R linters in VSCode

Tags: r, lintr

I'm trying to customize the linter settings in VSCode for R but I'm a little confused.

I've checked just about every source available, from SO questions to the `lintr` package vingette, but I'm stumbling on an issue. It could be that since I'm not a programmer I'm just not understanding something basic but essential.

[A question about line length linter 80 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481802/a-question-about-line-length-linter-80-characters)

[Disable R-linting in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858490/disable-r-linting-in-vscode)

[How to change the line length preference for warnings in Diagnostics? #3](https://github.com/REditorSupport/atom-ide-r/issues/3#issuecomment-374974483)

[Specify linters in lintr::lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913740/specify-linters-in-lintrlint)

[lintr github page](https://github.com/r-lib/lintr/blob/master/README.md#editors-setup)

[Lint R code in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/rtvs/linting-r-code?view=vs-2017)

[lintr v2.0.0](https://www.jimhester.com/post/lintr-2-0-0/)

[Using lintr](https://jimhester.r-universe.dev/articles/lintr/using_lintr.html#:%7E:text=The%20canonical%20way%20to%20configure%20R%20projects%20and,a%20settings%20file%20according%20to%20following%20prioritized%20list.)

It seems like I need to create a `.lintr` file in the folder that my script is in. Or possibly make changes in the `.lintr` file in the `lintr` package `~lintr/R/` folder?

I guess I'm just confused on the `.lintr` file. I tried creating files called "lintr", ".lintr" and "ScriptName.lintr", then added the following line to it, as described in the above sources:

```
linters: with_defaults(line_length_linter=line_length_linter(120L))
```

Then I reopened the script but whatever I do, `lintr` continues to default to 80 spaces. I think I'm doing something wrong with the `.lintr` file but I'm not sure what. I also tried changing file called "lintr" in the `lintr` package directory, but I can't save the file because it has no extension type (though it appears to be in the Debian Control Field Format, whatever that is). Windows keeps giving me a prompt to save as "txt".

I'd appreciate any step-by-step instructions to get past this issue.

Comment: are you able to install the development version of lintr? We've just added `lintr::use_lintr()` which is intended to simplify the setup process. see also https://github.com/r-lib/lintr/issues/902

Comment: @MichaelChirico Unfortunately, my organization won't allow me to install the development version.

Comment: I see... you might try copy-pasting the function source then. you only need to run the function once or a few times I reckon

Comment: @MichaelChirico Where is the source? I'm not seeing the function in the github (https://github.com/r-lib/lintr) code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry I spoke too soon! thought that PR was merged already. it's merged now

Comment: Using a .lintr file in the workspace directory with the line `linters: with_defaults(line_length_linter=line_length_linter(120L))` works for me once I restart VSCode.